# How to get a file as a byte array from a REST service

Tags: arrays, file, delphi, service

Can anyone describe to me how to get byte content from a SOAP or REST server using Delphi?

I want to get a file content from a service, and save it to a destination file.  My source service output is a byte array.

Comment: Open the file with a file stream. Read the size from the stream. Allocate a suitably sized byte array. Read from the stream into that byte array. TFile.ReadAllBytes does that for you in a simple helper method.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: the OP wants to consume a byte array produced by a remote SOAP/REST server, so what you describe does not apply.

Comment: OK, so the title is wrong. The request is to receive a byte array and write to a file. So it's TFile.WriteAllBytes instead.

Comment: @Masood: SOAP and REST are typically accessed over HTTP/S, so use any HTTP client library/API you want (Indy, ICS, Synapse, libCURL, WinInet/WinHTTP, etc). Depending on what version of Delphi you are actually using (you did not say), it may even have its own built-in SOAP/REST client components. Your question is too broad to answer definitively, and is not a good fit for StackOverflow.  Do some research, write some code, and if you run into problems, ask specific questions about that.

Comment: with special thanks to all you guys, a more detailed view of my problem is this: i have a web service ( both SOAP and REST versions of service are available) which reads a binary content from database and offers it as byte output. i'm have to get this service's binary content in a Delphi application and save it as a file in destination (my company's client machines).i've tried some scratches so on, but no success and im totally confused about it. will write my code here and you are appreciated to debug it for me

Answer (score 1):

i have tried this snippet found on web, but seems there is some thing missing yet:

```
STR := GetUrlContent('http://mySourceURL/idx.asmx/getApp?aid=12');
STR := PChar(PString(STR));
STRM := TStream.Create();
BinarySize := (Length(STR) + 1) * SizeOf(Char);
SetLength(StringAsBytes, BinarySize);
Move(STR[1], StringAsBytes[0], BinarySize);
```

Comment: my Delphi version in 6